# Why does this TSql return a blank or null value?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why does the @result value in the code below print out a blank string? I would expect it to concatenate with the previous result.

```
DECLARE @size int
DECLARE @string nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @result nvarchar(10)
SELECT  @string = '12345abc123'
DECLARE @count int, @total int
SELECT
    @total = LEN(@string),
    @count = 1

WHILE @count <= @total
    BEGIN
    SELECT  @result = SUBSTRING(@string, @count, 1) + '-'+ @result 
    SELECT  @count = @count + 1
    PRINT @result
    END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You never initialized `@result`, so it defaults to an sql `null`. SQL nulls are contagious poison, so when you do

```
SELECT @result = .... + @result
```

You're actually doing

```
SELECT @result = ... + null
```

and `@result` simply remains `null`

Initializing the value to an empty string solves your problem:

```
SET @result = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

It is returning a blank because you are concatenating the substring with @result, which initially is NULL.

Try setting @result to an empty string like this this:

```
SELECT  @string = '12345abc123', @result = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to initialize @result variable

Declare it like this

```
DECLARE @result nvarchar(10) = ''
```

this should work